# VLC will not install

Tags: 16.04, vlc

Trying to install VLC 16.04

sudo apt update
sudo apt install vlc

This is what I am getting

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5) but 2.2.4-6~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: please run `apt-cache showpkg vlc`and give us the `Versions` return of this command. Because I believe your troubles are coming from unmet dependencies due to a PPA. ( see 2.2.4-6~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1)

Comment: They closed it as duplicate, but if someone crosses by this question I gave proper solution on this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1072150/602887

Answer (score 3):

These are the resolutions for failed installs of default packages from the repository.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo apt install vlc
```

The commands above works because the depends are actually in the repository and needs to be sure to have the latest updates and upgrades of the packages.

Comment: OP got the same errors after trying this (just commenting here as they posted a new question stating as much instead of updating this one)

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for the information.  I haven't see the new question, yet.  In the meantime, consider informing the OP that he already has a question on the system and that he should check and add updates to the question he has active.

Comment: @Zanna Thanks. Not sure, but it may have been me that initiated the close.  I searched messages from the user just as I posted my comment to you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can we continue with my feedback or do I need to ask a separate question. I will post my progress below.

Comment: You don't have any feedback.  If you are referring to the answer you provided, your answer is out of place.  This is a question and answer site.  Questions are required to be something that can have a very specific answer.  An answer is something that applies and works for the question.  The comment section is for clarifications or comments about the question or answer that is provided.  If the question or answer doesn't apply in your case, you can ask a different question and possibly place a command to link to your new question.

Comment: Check this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1072150/602887

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package list.
Then:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clean up any partial packages.
Then:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to clean up the apt cache.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will clean up any unneeded dependencies.
If while doing this you can identify the broken package this code will very forcefully remove it.

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package name
```

Change package name to the real name of course.

This will fix your broken repositories and then :

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

will install vlc for you.