# Still VLC issues

Tags: 16.04

After this I get this

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo apt install vlc


billn@billn-N107:~$ sudo apt install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5) but 2.2.4-6~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
billn@billn-N107:~$
```

Comment: Why not trying aptitude or apt-get instead of apt?

Comment: I would guess he's using 16.04+ and no longer has aptitude and apt is favorable over apt-get. @ArijitChatterjee

Comment: opening up a 'new' question, that is the same as the old one is of no help to nobody - therefor flaged it as duplicate to the first one

Comment: Understood, but what's wrong in trying the long tested method once? New system may not have matured enough and fail sometime.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works fine for me. What ppa's have you added to your system? I would guess one of them are causing a conflict.

Comment: probably this ppa - https://launchpad.net/~nicola-onorata/+archive/ubuntu/desktop

Comment: You already have an active question on this issue.  Please use your other thread  [VLC will not install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/848629/vlc-will-not-install) for updates and resolution.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I'm pretty sure `apt` and `apt-get` are fundamentally the same. `apt` is just working to combine the features of `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, etc. I think the package manager functions are the same, just with a progress bar added.