# Installing VLC 3.0.1 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, ppa, vlc, snap

I am trying to install VLC in Ubuntu 16.04. By default, the version being provided from Ubuntu universe repositories is VLC version 2.2.2. But I checked the official website of VLC ( [Videolan](https://www.videolan.org/index.html) ), there I saw the latest version is 3.0.1.

I searched online on how to install latest VLC version, I got two solutions, either use a third-party PPA or use snaps. I searched for PPA, got [ppa:videolan/stable-daily](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily) which installs version 2.2.2 and [ppa:videolan/master-daily](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily) which installs version 4.0.0 rc1 (please correct me if I have gone wrong anywhere here).

So, finally, I resorted to snaps, installed VLC from it using `sudo snap install vlc --classic`. But the interface looked very weird to me, moreover, it downloaded 189 MB!

So is there any way to install the latest version using `apt-get`, the regular way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official release of latest VLC 3.0.2 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, you can get the latest VLC from the third party [packager](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf). To install VLC 3.0.2 in your system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) write the following commands in your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vlc-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Now you are done! But, please note that according to the statement by the  packager, there is no Chromecast support for this particular package of VLC Media Player on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. If you want that, then please upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3 no longer exists, using ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4 works

Answer (score 1):

In case that you had problems with unmet dependencies like I did, there is solution to add PPA `ffmpeg-4` and then you will be able to install it properly:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vlc-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Source: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vlc-3

Comment: Yep, that worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility yet to install VLC 3.0.1 via the APT package management system. There will be on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).

The newest VLC version is indeed 4.0, but it is still unstable.
The snap download has a large size, but why do you consider the interface to look weird?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw there are some inconsistencies in the interface. In windowed mode, it is quite difficult to click on the seek bar. And also the resume playback is not working in the snap version.

Answer (score -1):

I had some trouble with installing some dependencies, which got resolved after I added this repository to the list that Blackcoat77 posted:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

I'm a noob, so please correct this with the stable release, if you think it also contains the dependencies. My understanding is that there is little to no quality control on this release, so use with caution.